# The method click() does not work in drop-down list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could anyone help me with my issue? The method click() does not work in drop-down list in following code.

```
package com.driver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Listdown {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&hl=ru&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dtopnav-about-ru");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//strong[text()='Пол']/following-sibling::div/div[@role='listbox'])[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Мужской']/parent::div[@role='option']")).click();
     }
}
```

In the result I have to receive marked checkbox "Мужской" but I didn't.

Add html-code:

```
<div id="gender-form-element" class="form-element">
   <label id="gender-label">
     <strong id="GenderLabel">Пол</strong>
     <div id="Gender" class=" form-error" aria-invalid="true">
        <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" role="listbox" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" title="Пол" aria-activedescendant=":d">
        <div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical" style="-moz-user-select: none; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 21.5px; display: none;" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true">
           <div id=":e" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
           <div id=":f" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
              <div class="goog-menuitem-content">Мужской</div>
           </div>
           <div id=":g" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
           <div id=":h" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        </div>
        <input id="HiddenGender" type="hidden" name="Gender"/>
     </div>
   </label>
   <span id="errormsg_0_Gender" class="errormsg" role="alert">Это поле должно быть заполнено.</span>
```

Comment: Same code is working fine as i have tried in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by overinstall Selenium WebDriver 3.4.0 + Firefox 53.0 (64-bit). Before this I had WebDriver 2.53.1 + Firefox 47.0.2. Probably the issue was linked with environment, becouse the code is true.
Thanks all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works fine 
I've tried it on my environment and the text is chosen from the drop down list Correctly 
The only thing that I have changed is that I added the path to the gecko driver

here is your edited code that worked on my machine :

```
public class test1 {
    static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Eclipse\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&hl=ru&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dtopnav-about-ru");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//strong[text()='Пол']/following-sibling::div/div[@role='listbox'])[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Мужской']/parent::div[@role='option']")).click();
}
}
```

I'm using gecko driver : geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64

My Firefox Browser version  is : 51.0.1

So the problem might be related to your environment

Comment: Yes, thank you for answer. I have just seen this and this morning already reinstall webdriver.

Answer (score -1):

Instead, you could warp your WebElement into **Select** Object and use method as shown below:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement("Your locator goes here"));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Мужской");
```

You may use selectByValue() or selectByIndex instead of previous method if you like to.

**Edit:**

I have seen the page you were working on and modified your code.

First, click the dropdown:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#Gender > div > div")).click();
```

Then, call the method as follows:

```
selectItemFromList(By.cssSelector("#Gender > div[class='goog-menu goog-menu-vertical'] > div > div"), "Your item name goes here");  // you can any locator here for other dropdown menu
```

Here's the method implementation you called earlier:

```
static void selectItemFromList(By element, String itemName){
          List<WebElement> itemList = driver.findElements(element);

            for(WebElement item : itemList){
                if(item.getText().trim().equals(itemName)){
                    item.click();
                    break;
                }
            }
      }
```

Comment: There is no select tag for that. And the code provide by OP is working fine at my end as I have tried in chrome

Comment: Can you provide the HTML part then?

Comment: Yes, as Narendra Rajput said, Select is not working here.

Comment: @optimist_creeper, you can see this code in any browser. The link is true.

Comment: @optimist_creeper, I have just run your edit code but he doesn't work ((